# Debugging with shell programming and cpp files?

Tags: shell, shell-script, c++

I am having trouble understanding how my code is working. I am new to this project and never learned unix before. My coworker quickly showed me how to run the program but didn't explain how it worked

After making sure all the C++ files compiled properly by running make, he went to the command prompt and typed `./run.sh list.txt`

I took a look at the `run.sh` file. It is below:

```
DIR=/directory/scripts/binaries/what

LIST=$1

while read PDF
do 
    echo "HOLD ON ${PDF}..." 
    ./makeInputAX.sh ${PDF} ${PDF} >INPUT/${PDF}.something 
    ${DIR} -AX INPUT/${PDF}.something # I don't want to reveal the actual types of files I'm dealing with, so I called them 'something'
done < ${LIST}
```

the `makeInputAX.sh` file is:

```
$PDF=1
echo "THEFILE ABC/{PDF}.something"
```

and `list.txt` simply contains:

```
12345
```

So I already know that `run.sh` reads whats inside `list.txt`, and assigns `12345` to be the `LIST` variable. I do see `HOLD ON 12345` in the command prompt. What confuses me is that I thought `run.sh` runs first, then calls `makeInputAX.sh`, so how can `PDF` be assigned to `list.txt`, when that assignment was in `makeInputAX.sh` not `run.sh`?

What also confuses me is that in the command prompt, I then see the outputs from the program, as they were written in the cpp files that are part of the project. However, those files are in a seperate directory, not in `/directory/scripts/binaries/what`. I made changes to those cpp files and want to see the new outputs I should get, but I am getting an error:

```
 could not open the somethingelse file for read
```

However, `could not open the ..` is not written anywhere in my C++ code. To fix that, do I need to look in my cpp files or is there something to these sh files that can help?

Answer (score 2):

`$1` is the first argument to the script, i.e. `list.txt`

```
LIST=$1
```

simply copies that filename to the `LIST` variable, so `$LIST` now contains `lists.txt` as well -- it doesn't contain `12345`.

```
while read PDF
do
    ...
done < ${LIST}
```

starts a loop whose standard input is redirected to the file `list.txt`, and each time through the loop it reads a line from the file into the variable `PDF`. So `$PDF` will then contain `12345.

The variables in `makeInputAX.sh` are unrelated to the variables in `run.sh`. So they each have their own variables named `PDF`, and they operate independently. The only exception would be environment variables, which are declared using the `export` command; environment variables set in a calling script are copied to the environment of the scripts it calls (but not the other way around).

I don't see anything in your scripts that could be producing the "could not open the somethingelse file for read", it must be coming from the C++ program. It's possible it's in a library that your program calls, so you wouldn't see the message anywhere in your code.

Your `makeInputAX.sh` script doesn't look correct, though. It should probably be something like this:

```
PDF=1
echo "THEFILE ABC/${PDF}.something"
```

You put `$` before a variable when inserting its value in another command, you don't use it in the assignment. You had it backwards, with the `$` in the assignment, but not in the `echo` command.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm still confused as to how the C++ files and the shell scripts are even related. `DIR=/directory/scripts/binaries/what` probably has something to do with it, but how?

Comment: The shell script just does the same thing as if you'd typed these commands by hand. `${DIR}` is replaced by that value, so it runs the `what` program with the arguments in the shell script. I assume that's the C++ program that you compiled.

Comment: I also don't understand why some (not all) of the outputs in the C++ files, that is `cout` don't display on the command prompt.

Comment: I don't see any reason why the output of the programs wouldn't appear on the screen. You're not redirecting the output to a file.